# How do I change the SalesForce endpoint in PHP

Tags: php, salesforce

I am using the PHP library: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP

As I understand it, this is the most "official" library. How do I change the endpoint to use the `test.salesforce.com` sandbox instead of the production SalesForce?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to log into the sandbox account and download new WSDL from that environment.

Setup > Develop > API